# Why does Gatling still sends requests when scenario injection is on nothingFor?

Tags: scala, gatling

So I have the following scenario:

```
  setUp(scenario.inject(
    nothingFor(30 seconds), // 1
    rampUsers(10) during (30 seconds),
    nothingFor(1 minute),
    rampUsers(20) during (30 seconds)
  ).protocols(httpconf)).maxDuration(3 minutes)
```

I expected this scenario to start by doing nothing for 30 seconds, ramping up 10 users over 30 seconds, do nothing(pause) for a minute and finish by ramping up 20 users for 30 seconds.

But what I got is a 30 second pause, ramp up 10 users over 30 seconds, steady state of 10 users for a minute and then an additional ramp up of 20 users. (I ended up running 30 users)

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: it seems that your scenario never terminates?

Answer (score 2):

The injection profiles only specify when users start a scenario, not how long they're active for - that will be determined by how long it takes for a user to finish the scenario. So when you ramp 10 users over 30 seconds one user will start the scenario every 3 seconds, but they keep running until they finish (however long that is). I'm guessing your scenario takes more than a couple of minutes for a user to complete.

Comment: Thanks! is there any way to force pause through the injection? or set the pause time to inherit form inject?

Comment: As far as i know, there's no injection like "wait until all users are finished then..." Depending on your scenario, you may be able to use "rendezvous" to achieve something close to what you want

Comment: what does your scenario look like? lots of loops or use of 'forever'?

Comment: Yes, I now realise that I need to set loops time to correspond with my expected flow logic and try to avoid forevers.